# Is it possible to create a plugin inside a plugin with CakePHP?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I am attemping to create a Plugin inside a Plugin using the CakePHP Framework.

My folder structure is like so

```
app/Plugin/SbnAdmin/Plugin/SbnChart/.....
```

I am using the following line to load the SbnAdmin plugin

```
CakePlugin::loadAll(array('SbnAdmin' => array('bootstrap' => true)));
```

And in the SbnAdmin bootstrap I have

```
CakePlugin::loadAll();
```

I am able to view a controller/model/view from the SbnAdmin plugin, but I am unable to access the SbnChart plugin...

I have tried

```
www..../sbn_admin/sbn_chart/chart/index
www..../sbn_chart/chart/index
```

With no success and I am not sure what else I can do, Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your SbnAdmin bootstrap add:

```
App::build(array('Plugin' => array(CakePlugin::path('SbnAdmin') . 'Plugin' . DS)));
CakePlugin::load('SbnChart');
```

What we're doing is telling cake to add additional paths to look for to load the plugins, in this case inside your SbnAdmin/Plugin folder. Then we are loading the plugin afterwards.

You should be able to access it now via the normal `/plugin_name/controller/action` or in your case `/sbn_chart/controller/action`

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much, Your line wasn't working for me, however, the following line did

    App::build(array('Plugin' => array(CAKE . '../../app/Plugin/SbnAdmin/Plugin/')));

Comment: Yeah, the `DS` must be moved to the end: `App::build(array('Plugin' => array(CakePlugin::path('SbnAdmin') . 'Plugin' . DS)));`