# Is it possible to create a plugin inside a plugin with CakePHP3?

Tags: cakephp-3.0

I would like to create a plugin inside a plugin with **Cakephp3**. I found a solution for Cakephp2 but it doesn't seem to work in Cakephp3:

[Is it possible to create a plugin inside a plugin with CakePHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11817818/is-it-possible-to-create-a-plugin-inside-a-plugin-with-cakephp)

How can I do this in Cakephp3?

Comment: Surely possible, but the first thing that would come to my mind, is the question why exactly you would want to do that in the first place?

Comment: I'm developing a plugin that could be extended with other plugins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume your question regards having the plugin **loaded** in your CakePHP 3.x application, not **creating** the plugin :-)

**Note**: this answer assumes you installed Cake using composer.

As an example, let's say we wanted to create a plugin, **Themes**, and this plugin was going to contain other plugins, **Blue** and **Red**.

By convention, the **Themes** plugin should be contained in *your_app/plugins/Themes* and the **Blue** and **Red** plugins could be contained in *your_app/plugins/Themes/plugins/Blue* and *your_app/plugins/Themes/plugins/Red* respectively.

In *your_app/config/bootstrap.php* , add the following:

```
Plugin::load('Themes', ['bootstrap' => true]);
```

(See https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/plugins.html#plugin-configuration for info regarding plugin configuration)

The code above tells Cake to load the Themes plugin, and to look for and load the plugin's bootstrap file.

If you haven't already done so, create the Themes plugin's bootstrap file at *your_app/plugins/Themes/config/bootstrap.php* and have it looking similar to:

```
<?php

use Cake\Core\Plugin;

// load the red and blue child plugins
Plugin::load('Themes/plugins/Red');
Plugin::load('Themes/plugins/Blue');
```

**Important**: Since you're trying to write the plugin(s) manually and not installing via composer, you need to modify *your_app/composer.json* to contain something like:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "src",
        "Red\\": "./plugins/Themes/plugins/Red/src",
        "Blue\\": "./plugins/Themes/plugins/Blue/src"
    }
}
```

(See https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/plugins.html#autoloading-plugin-classes for more info on autoloading plugin classes).

Now, from within *your_app/* run:

```
php composer.phar dumpautoload
```

(or the equivalent command, depending on how composer was installed on your machine)

This tells composer to refresh its autoloading cache. If you were to inspect *your_app/vendor/cakephp-plugins.php*, you should see that a path to the Themes plugin's folder has been added to a pre-existing list of plugin paths.

Now, from within your app's main controllers, you should be able to have stuff like:

```
public function initialize()
{
    // load (supposedly-existing) components from the "Red" or "Blue" themes
    // load GradientComponent of the "Red" theme
    $this->loadComponent('Red.Gradient');

    // load ColorComponent of the "Blue" theme
    $this->loadComponent('Blue.Color');

    // use what you asked for...
    $this->Color->someMethod(['data']);

    parent::initialize();
}
```

Also, to use view files (that you'd expect theme plugins to provide :-) ):

```
public function beforeRender(Event $event)
{
    // use the "home" layout from the Red theme
    $this->viewBuilder()->setLayout('Themes/plugins/Red.home');

    parent::beforeRender($event);
}
```